# Can the observer pattern be used to provide immediate notification on the web?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, design-patterns, observer-pattern

Let's say you have a simple game of dice.  It is played on the web.  Player 1 rolls, then player 2.  There needs to be some mechanism to notify a player when it is their turn.  Due to the webs stateless, [pull](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology) based nature, the solution seems to be less obvious than a windows application.

- One way is to poll the server at regular intervals.  >,<

MS talks about [active MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649643.aspx).  Essentially it's MVC that applies the observer pattern.  So, the game itself is the "subject" and player1, player2 are observers.

Can observer be used as a solution to immediate notification on the web?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](http://bhavin.directi.com/opening-a-bi-directional-socket-from-a-browser) is a good summary of techniques to achieve bidirectional communication:

- Comet
- Long-polling
- Flash
- Web Sockets
- Java Applets
- Browser plugin
- External application
- Other methods:  ActiveX, Silverlight, Orbited

You're right that players would observe the game state. A long-held poll would be a way of letting the player know who's turn it is, and other game state information.

Comment: So, then yes but only with the help of one of these mechanisms.

Answer (score 1):

We are using long-waiting HTTP requests for similar functionality. What you do is you do a HTTP request to server with loong timeout set on client (say, 10 minutes). In server handler you do WaitOne(serverTimeout) with a bit shorter timeout (8 minutes) on some synchronization object which is triggered on event - and return the answer immediately ofter event happens or when timeout expires.

It's handy to use AsyncController for such queries.